# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library (windows 64 bit)

Tags: php, wampserver, sqlsrv

I am using windows 10 64 bit system. I installed wamppserver (Download link : https://excellmedia.dl.sourceforge.net/project/wampserver/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/wampserver3.1.3_x64.exe)in my machine. After i try to add sqlsrv extension (Download link (Already tried 3.1 and 3.2): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)but i got following error. How to solve this error. Advance thanks.

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64latest/bin/php/php5.6.35/ext/php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: One of the endless examples for why a SoftwareManagement system as present in Linux systems saves so much time and hassle compared to a MS-Windows environment where software installation still needs to be done as back in the wild west times...

Comment: It looks like you are running PHP5.6.35 **but you have installed a `php_sqlsrc` that is built to run with PHP 5.5** Thats what the `55` means in the filename `php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll`

Answer (score 0):

You don't comply with the [System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017). You need PHP/7.0 or greater if you want to use the 64-bit architecture.

Options:

- Upgrade PHP to 7.0+
- Migrate your stack to 32-bit

Comment: Not strictly true. There are `experimental` versions of 64bit PHP5.6. Admittedly thay are not truly 64bit but they do run in 64bit

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was referring to the SQLSRV extension. They didn't distribute 64-bit binaries until version 4 (if I recall correctly) and such version requires PHP/7.0 or greater. I saw unofficial binaries but they were partly hacks because the original code didn't really compile for such platform.